# Publisher vs AnyPublisher in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

What is the role of AnyPublisher in Combine, and why in many examples, including in[WWDC Combine In practice, 27:40](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/) they return AnyPublisher, using `.eraseToAnyPublisher`, and not just return a Publisher?

The [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher) says

> Use AnyPublisher to wrap a publisher whose type has details you don’t want to expose to subscribers or other publishers.

But can anyone give an example of where it can be useful?

Comment: You should read up on type erasure. [This](http://robnapier.net/erasure) article nicely explains the reasoning behind type erasure and why you would want to use it. Bear in mind that Swift 5.1's opaque return types solves the issue of not being able to use PATs as concrete types, which was previously one of the main reasons for using type erasure, but the other use cases still apply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Publisher` is a Protocol with associated types, while `AnyPublisher` is a *struct*.

Try casting to `Publisher` and you get an error

```
let x = Just(1) as Publisher
```

> Protocol 'Publisher' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

This despite the fact that `Just` is a `Publisher`.

The `Publisher` type can't be utilized in the same way as `AnyPublisher` to achieve type erasure.

Where you could use `Publisher` is when you define a function that has generics as part of the definition.

#### Most common reason to use `AnyPublisher`:

Return an instance of a Publisher from a function.

#### Most common reason to use `Publisher`:

Create a protocol extension to create a custom Combine operator. For example:

```
extension Publisher {
  public func compactMapEach<T, U>(_ transform: @escaping (T) -> U?)
    -> Publishers.Map<Self, [U]>
    where Output == [T]
  {
    return map { $0.compactMap(transform) }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about just using ```some Publisher```? That works

Comment: @smat88dd if you have a better answer, please add it!

Comment: @smat88dd I thinks `some  Publisher` will cause some error when compiler converting to concrete type. So it's not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Publisher is a protocol and AnyPublisher is a concrete implementation of Publisher.

AnyPublisher is a type-erased struct that conforms the Publisher protocol. Type erasure allows to hide details about the publisher that may not want to expose to subscribers — or downstream publishers.

Note:
AnyPublisher does not have a send(_:) operator, so new values cannot be added to that publisher.

Comment: this seems to come from RayWenderlich.com. Provide credit if true.

Comment: Note: *Publisher* does not have a send(_:) operator. That is defined on the Subject protocol, which conforms to and extends Publisher.